# How XMLReader from PHP library will deal with condition when millions of users reading/searching something from a large XML? Will it hang or process?

Tags: php, xml, architecture, filesystems, system-design

I know XMLReader from PHP https://www.php.net/xmlreader can read/search something from XML and return data using file-path.

```
$xml = new XMLReader(); 
$xml->open('test.xml'); 
//Do Something with file test.xml and return searched data
$xml->close();
```

But I just wanted to know what if millions of user are visiting the page concurrently which uses above function, means open the file return what user wants and then close the file.

Then how this will deal if user load is million?

Will it hang the system of read from same file open at once, without opening that again?

But what function says it will open every-time & close.

I just tried above function and it was returning the data from XML which I needed but I am just confused with their open and close process each time. Then if at same time millions of users are searching different thing from XML that uses same function to return data, how it will handle the scenario.

Comment: If it doesn't lock the file when reading then multiple processes should be able to read it at once. But this will still be inefficient when you get a lot of users, especially if you're then using php to search inside the data. This sounds like a clear use case for a well designed database which can scale. If you're really expecting the quantities of concurrent users that you've mentioned in your question then surely you have a team of people working on this application including an architect, and performance testing planned, and so on? Sounds like it should be a big serious project

Comment: Actually one 3rd API is there which returns big XML file(50MB) in response and they update their data every half a day(12 hours), so searching 50 MB in DB is taking time so I thought it would be good if we go via file system because there are factorial 10 combination (3628800 combination) of that big XML means 3628800 files are there with 50 MB each, which also getting updated every 12 hours. So I was taking their 50MB data from each combination when user requires that combination and saving it to file & then searching into it and returning data & we are having 1 million user. Please suggest.

Comment: `searching 50 MB in DB is taking time`...50MB is a **tiny** amount of data for a modern database. If you insert the data in a sensibly normalised structure and write your queries properly, searching that database will always be more efficient than parsing an XML file and searching it using PHP every time a request is made. SQL is explicitly designed for efficiently searching through huge datasets, in a way that PHP (or most other regular programming languages) isn't. Of course we have no visibility of what database design you may have used which led to it being slow.

Comment: Now, you say there are many different combinations which lead you to download thousands of these 50MB files...of course I don't know what they contain or whether some of this data is actually duplicated but with a slightly different format, or what. But I'd guess that there is probably a more efficient way to download and store the data in bulk, for efficient storage. Either that or maybe you should consider making more targeted calls to the API on-demand, if it supports that. It's difficult to suggest a precise solution when we know so little about the data involved, to be honest.

Comment: Thanks for your quick and informative response. Those data of each 50 MB data combination is different unique and not same. So just give me an idea on my this thought:
First I am making one call to one of the combination then I am receiving 50 MB unique XML in response and I am saving directly that response in our one big text column in Mysql.
After that when other user click on same combination result I should check in my table based on combination if that exists or not.
And if that is same I should return from DB which is raw XML
And at last searching the required key in that XML to show

Comment: `I am saving directly that response in our one big text column`...well that certainly isn't efficient and does not take advantage of any of the benefits of a correctly normalised schema. I'd have been expecting that you wrote some code to parse the XML and insert individual data items from it into a pre-defined schema which reflects the same data structure, but in a SQL format (e.g. tables, relationships, constraints etc) so that you could then query it efficiently with SQL. Just dumping the XML string into a single mysql field is no better than putting it into a text file, of course.

Comment: Is this correct way? because anyhow I need to check that XML so if I search via DB to load raw XML in memory it will take more time and will hang. Can you suggest my other DB thought.

Comment: I got you, that means I need to parse XML before inserting into structured DB column, table structures Right? If yes then how to parse 50 MB on the fly before inserting into DB?

Comment: Firstly I'd expect you would do this as a background job (e.g. a scheduled task via cron or Windows Scheduled Tasks). Then you can write some code to parse the data using whatever structure is relevant, and then insert it into the database. Obviously, first you will need to design the database correctly too. I can't tell you precisely how to do that because, again, I know absolutely nothing about the data or what you need to store from it. But you can use the XML-reading tools in PHP to help you parse the XML.

Comment: THANKS AGAIN. But the problem is I can not run cron JOB or scheduled task in background because that data changes frequently in their API in each 12 hours with new data/updated data. and their is 5 million of combination of 50 MB each which they used to update every 12 hours. So I need something when user ask for data, otherwise I need to schedule 5 million combination of each 50 MB and then need to take care of 12 hour update then again schedule 5 million data in each 12 hour, Is that what you are suggesting. I got your other part DB solution.

Comment: Why can't you do that? Doing something on a schedule (e.g. to update everything every 12 hours) is exactly what cron is for. Even if it doesn't update everything instantly, it would gradually update over the time period, and hopefully be complete before the next update is due.

Comment: So just take an example in future there will be 10 million XML data each segregated in 1 GB per API response from 3rd party which they updates each 12 hours, Is it possible to get all sync all in correct structure in each 12 hours before next job schedule.

Comment: That depends on many things - the speed of responses from the API, the efficiency of the code you write, and the speed and availability of the hardware resources you're running the code on.

Comment: Their API response is very slow. Can you suggest what I need to do in that case? I don't want my users to face same issue.

Comment: Well a background task ought to make that a less serious issue for your users, since they are not calling it directly, but reading from your database instead. So that should improve your front-end performance. If you find you can't refresh all the data in the 12-hour cycle, you can perhaps have guidance on your app to explain to them that data may occasionally be slightly out of date due to processing times. There's not a lot else you can do to improve the API's download speed, other than to increase your own network bandwidth (if that's the bottleneck) or complain to the API provider.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson, Is it good way to call API directly? I don't think so as per standard, as you are describing things in much clear way as an good architect, I want your input in this also.

Comment: Sorry can you clarify with a bit more context, I don't really understand the question.

Comment: Should I call data directly from API on each call? Is this good way?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. "Directly" as opposed to what? And how are you defining "call"? If you're talking about every time a user requests data in your front-end, then no...I've already suggested using a cron job to avoid the slowness and inefficiency of that.